# codenameone post request dont send argument

Tags: php, codenameone

I tried to make a post rquest form codename one :

```
ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
        r.setPost(true);
        r.setHttpMethod("POST");
        r.setUrl(GlobalVariable.REST_HOSTNAME + "/api/newsfeed");
        r.addArgument("content", message);
        r.addArgument("title", "Update");
        r.addArgument("uid", "admin");
        r.addArgument("token", Preferences.get("token", null));
        r.addArgument("eid", Preferences.get("eventId", ""));
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
```

when I checked from php log, no parameter submitted :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2016:01:01:08 +0700] "POST /api/newsfeed HTTP/1.1" 401 7581
```

but, if I used postman, it succeeded. How to make or force the argument to be passed?

Comment: Check the network monitor from the simulator

Comment: Post the command you used with postman. I'm guessing the webservice requires JSON

Comment: here my post url via postman : http://danone.local/api/newsfeed?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjgyLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9kYW5vbmUubG9jYWxcL2FwaVwvYXV0aFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NzM1Mjc5ODMsImV4cCI6MTQ3MzUzMTU4MywibmJmIjoxNDczNTI3OTgzLCJqdGkiOiJhNTE4YjFlMGVmZTYwZDk5YTM0ZTIwNjRiMTNhNmE5NyJ9.479VP8x3SuUFJVI_VblSZkg2au5xEEVQYNPetsGEzso&content=content2&title=title2&eid=0e30cbddbdfde8b50bb12fddd5642d70&uid=admin

Comment: I checked with network monitor and copy the post body into postman, the result is correct. shows 200 response code. but when i post with codename one the response code is 401.

Comment: Your php access log won't show post parameters.  Add logging to your error log and see what your script receives.

Comment: finally find the root cause, it's because of apache discard the Authorization header connection if the request  was not proper base64 url encoded. source : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication . Is there any way to set the ConnectionRequest to proper base64 encoded?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the webservice above requires a JSON argument whereas Codename One defaults to standard post arguments (like HTML form). You can submit JSON using code such as this: [How to post JSON to a REST webservice in codenameone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063909/how-to-post-json-to-a-rest-webservice-in-codenameone/39071037)

Comment: I was not convert it to json yet, I checked with network monitor and copy the post body into postman, the result is correct. shows 200 response code. but when i post with codename one the response code is 401.

Comment: finally find the root cause, it's because of apache discard the Authorization header connection if the request  was not proper base64 url encoded. source : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication . Is there any way to set the ConnectionRequest to proper base64 encoded?

Comment: We have a base 64 class but we don't send authorization headers